# What is the best web browser control to use on Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, web, webbrowser-control

I am looking for a web browser control or any technology that can render web pages on a Windows Form Application Faster. Any suggestions? I am using .Net and the built-in web browser control is not an option to me because it has a lot of issues and is slow. I've tried GeckoFX and so far I considered it good enough. It's rather slow but faster than the .Net web browser control and it has a lot of good features too.

**Update**

I've been testing a lot of web browser control and we end up using Awesomium. Great web browser control for windows app And is fast too. Here is the link http://awesomium.com/

Comment: Keep your machine updated,  Gecko is falling behind.  You get the WebBrowser speedup for free with IE9.  http://internet-browser-review.toptenreviews.com/

Comment: I've used Awesomium but it seems did not load saved file HTMLs very good. Specially when there is some images in file! That was slow too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried these:

[**WebKit .NET**](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) 
It is a WinForms control library wrapper for WebKit written in C#. The aim is to make it easy for developers to incorporate WebKit into their .NET applications.

[**GeckoFX**](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) 
It is a Windows Forms control written in clean, commented C# that embeds the Mozilla Gecko browser control in any Windows Forms Application. It also contains a simple class model providing access to the HTML and CSS DOM.

[**MozNet**](http://se7en-soft.com/moznet/getmoznet.aspx) 
It is an alternative wrapper for Gecko that claims to be more active than GeckoFX.

Comment: which one is good with running jquery statements ? :D @coder