# vb.net + webbrowser/webkitbrowser + collada viewer

Tags: vb.net, html, collada

I am currently working on a vb.net application (winforms) and my task is to somehow import collada files(.dae) files and make them viewable from inside the application.

What worked for me is this: In a simple html5 webpage, I used three.js, colladaloader.js and I was able to view the animation in my web browser.

So I thought I can just import this into the vb.net application using the webrowser/webkotbrowser toolbox component. But alas, what worked in a normal html browser did not inside the application.

The browser that we import in the application doesn't support webgl (even the webkit version doesn't support it).

This is what I get instead of the animation

[image: WebGL error message]

Again, it works fine inside a web browser like Chrome or Safari, but not IE.

Any help to make this possible in vb.net is highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, everything is in the error message...

Comment: I understand the error Bart, I want a solution. I tried something and it didnt work. Can you help me with some direction. If you can find a component that I can embed in the application that will be great. I am ready to forego the idea of webkit inside the application.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of any more help on this. I'm not even sure it is a correct question for SO.... I would doubt there is a viable solution already in place when even IE10 doesn't support WebGL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have to use a NON-IE based web browser control, see this post:

[What is the best web browser control to use on Windows Form Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147434/what-is-the-best-web-browser-control-to-use-on-windows-form-application)

his geckoFX link is outdated I think...

http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/

This one costs money:

http://awesomium.com/

Comment: Mr Jason Bayldon. :) your idea worked. I tried everything from chromium embedded framework to webkitdotnet. Nothing was easily working. Geckofx works beautifully.